# How does Steve Reich's music have more 'modernist rigor' than Philip Glass's?

Tags: terminology

Source: [*The Complete Classical Music Guide*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0756692563) (2012). General Editor: John Burrows OBE HonRCM, edited with [Charles Wiffen](https://theconversation.com/profiles/charles-wiffen-142851). [p. 297 Bottom Right](https://books.google.com/books?id=w5hGTCM8WE0C&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=%22there+is+often+an+atmosphere+of+tension+and%22&source=bl&ots=Ua68lcTh4M&sig=E2VCohqtrPKMoxxlq0Z1RUNZDqY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbsojIhMbbAhXErFkKHShoDBcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=pattern%20games&f=false).

> #### INFLUENCES
>
> Reich’s effect on musical culture is perhaps
> not as great as Philip Glass’s, although within
> classical circles his influence may be greater,
> owing to the **modernist rigor of his music**.
> Nonetheless, his characteristic pattering,
> marimba-and-winds sound has managed to
> spread further, appearing on pop remix albums

What does 'modernist rigor' signify here? Is Reich somehow more Minimalist than Glass?

Comment: 'Rigor' usually implies 'refusal to compromise', and in this context, would probably mean 'refusal to be commercial'. Not able to comment from musical POV as I only known a few pieces by either composer, but perhaps someone with more knowledge of the actual music can take the idea and craft an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on Reich's music, but his *[Music For 18 Musicians](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXJWO2FQ16c)* seems very tightly focused on the singular idea of the transformations possible in the sheer texture of sound, even given a large number of constants (such as the constant sixteenth note pulse in this song). Glass's music is more varied, and less focused, at least comparatively.